Label not coming after crossing
I have one code. I need to gernerate label and alerts if the crossover or under happens.If crossover happens ( even if it touches UP line, I need label(not after close) , I nedd a DOWN arrow and if cross under happens I need a UP arrow( even if it touches DOWN line, I need label(not after close).
I have attached image for more clarity.
Could some one please help?
Thanks,
Mayur Sabane
Tried writting label.new but its not working
//@version=5
MAX_LINES_COUNT = 500
indicator("TEST", "", true, max_lines_count = MAX_LINES_COUNT, max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back=1000)

color hiPivotColorInput  = input(color.new(color.lime, 0), "High pivots")
color loPivotColorInput  = input(color.new(color.fuchsia, 0), "Low pivots")
int   pivotLegsInput     = input.int(5, "Pivot legs")
int   qtyOfPivotsInput   = input.int(50, "Quantity of last pivots to remember", minval = 0, maxval = MAX_LINES_COUNT / 2)
int   maxLineLengthInput = input.int(500, "Maximum line length in bars", minval = 2)

// ————— Queues a new element in an array and de-queues its first element.
qDq(array, qtyOfElements, arrayElement) =>
    array.push(array, arrayElement)
    if array.size(array) > qtyOfElements
        // Only deqeue if array has reached capacity.
        array.shift(array)

// —————— Loop through an array of lines, extending those that price has not crossed and deleting those crossed.
checkLinesForBreaches(arrayOfLines) =>
    int qtyOfLines = array.size(arrayOfLines)
    // Don't loop in case there are no lines to check because "to" value will be `na` then`.
    for lineNo1 = 0 to (qtyOfLines > 0 ? qtyOfLines - 1 : na)
        // Need to check that array size still warrants a loop because we may have deleted array elements in the loop.
        lineNo=qtyOfLines-lineNo1-1
        if lineNo < array.size(arrayOfLines)
            line  currentLine    = array.get(arrayOfLines, lineNo)
            float lineLevel      = line.get_price(currentLine, bar_index)
            bool  lineWasCrossed = math.sign(close[1] - lineLevel) != math.sign(close - lineLevel)
            bool  lineIsTooLong  = bar_index - line.get_x1(currentLine) > maxLineLengthInput
            if lineWasCrossed or lineIsTooLong
            
              //  label newlabel = label.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput] + 5,high, text="", color=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, size = size.tiny)
              //  label newlabe2 = label.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput] + 5,low, text="", color=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, size = size.tiny)
                
                // Line stays on the chart but will no longer be extend on further bars.
                array.remove(arrayOfLines, lineNo)
                // Force type of both local blocks to same type.
                int(na)

            
            else
                line.set_x2(currentLine, bar_index)
                int(na)






// Arrays of lines containing non-crossed pivot lines.
var line[] hiPivotLines = array.new_line(qtyOfPivotsInput)
var line[] loPivotLines = array.new_line(qtyOfPivotsInput)

// Detect new pivots.
float hiPivot = ta.pivothigh(pivotLegsInput, pivotLegsInput)
float loPivot = ta.pivotlow(pivotLegsInput, pivotLegsInput)
//plot(hiPivot)

// Create new lines on new pivots.
if not na(hiPivot)
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput], hiPivot, bar_index, hiPivot, color = hiPivotColorInput)
    
    //label newlabel = label.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput],hiPivot, text="", color=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, size = size.tiny)
    line.delete(qDq(hiPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newLine))
else if not na(loPivot)
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput], loPivot, bar_index, loPivot, color = loPivotColorInput)
    line.delete(qDq(loPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newLine))
    //label newlabel = label.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput],loPivot, text="", color=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, size = size.tiny)

// Extend lines if they haven't been crossed by price.
checkLinesForBreaches(hiPivotLines)
checkLinesForBreaches(loPivotLines)


